# How to define hyperlink click event on the fly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

I am stuck on something: I am creating a hyperlink at runtime that has a navigation URL. I need to define its click event so that I can save a few values to the database. I did something like below but without success.

Could you please suggest an alternative?

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item is GridDataItem) {
    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)gridDataItem["ContentTitle"].Controls[0];
    link.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
    link.ToolTip = Common.grdTextCell(gridDataItem["ContentSummaryDescr"].Text);
    link.NavigateUrl = "~/SomePath/" + gridDataItem["ContentName"].Text;
    link.Target = "_blank";
    link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" +
      dummyBtn.ClientID + "').click();");
  }
}

protected void dummyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

But the button click event is not firing, it simply navigates to the URL. What to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a LinkButton, not a HyperLink.

Here's some sample code to get you started (not tested)

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        LinkButton link = (LinkButton)gridDataItem["ContentTitle"].Controls[0];
        link.Click += dummyBtn_Click;
    }
}

protected void dummyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("dummyBtn_Click");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a server side event to fire you would need a `LinkButton` and not a `HyperLink`

`LinkButton` has a `Click` event handler which you can use.

`HyperLink` only redirects and has no corresponding Click event handler associated for server side code

Comment: yes that's y i can't use LinkBUtton..the above code is implemented and the click event is firing now, but now i am unable to fix on which row is called so that i can insert the values....and unfortunately my RadGrid1_ItemDataBound also not firing, i am so stuck..........help me god..

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Link Button. Just replace your Hyperlink with LinkButton in  your code.It should work.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item is GridDataItem) {
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton )gridDataItem["ContentTitle"].Controls[0];
    link.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Navy;
    link.ToolTip = Common.grdTextCell(gridDataItem["ContentSummaryDescr"].Text);
    link.NavigateUrl = "~/SomePath/" + gridDataItem["ContentName"].Text;
    link.Target = "_blank";
    link.Click += dummyBtn_Click;

  }
}

protected void dummyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

Comment: link do not support NavigationUrl